# What is the HAML equivalent for the ERB white space removal closing expression symbol (-%>)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

Does anybody know how can I write the equivalent of the following in pure HAML? Note that I want to display 2 select boxes one exactly next to each other and next to them a button, without any white space in between:

```
<%= f.select :state, State.all.order(:name).map {|s| [s.name, s.id]} -%>
<%= f.select :subject, Subject.all.order(:name).map {|s| [s.name, s.id]} -%>
<%= f.button "Search", class: "input-lg" -%>
```

**Edit** This is included inside a partial like the following:

```
= form_for @tutors_search_form, url: "/tutors/search", method: :get do |f|
  .container
    .row.text-center
      :erb
        <%= f.text_field :subject, class: "input-lg input-no-border-radius", placeholder: "What Subject do you want to learn?", required: true, id: 'home-page-search-bar-subject-input' -%>
        <%= f.text_field :state, class: "input-lg input-no-border-radius", placeholder: "Which State are you in?", required: true, id: 'home-page-search-bar-state-input' -%>
        <%= f.button "Search", class: "btn btn-primary-wouaou btn-lg btn-no-border-radius", id: 'home-page-search-bar-form-button-submit' -%>
```

As you can see, I have to use `:erb` inside the `HAML` file. Otherwise, I cannot make it generate the input tags and the button without blanks in between.

Comment: I really want to understand why this question has been downvoted two times. Please, let me know so that I can improve my questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question. I had the same exact problem. I have a question that gets negative votes as well. I actually didn't know you could include ERB within HAML, so your question was also an answer to an unasked question of mine.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it should be:

```
<= f.select :state, State.all.order(:name).map {|s| [s.name, s.id]}
<= f.select :subject, Subject.all.order(:name).map {|s| [s.name, s.id]}
<= f.button "Search", class: "input-lg"
```

HAML Documentation:

[**Whitespace Removal: `>` and `<`**](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)

> `>` and `<` give you more control over the whitespace near a tag. `>`
>   will remove all whitespace surrounding a tag, while `<` will remove
>   all whitespace immediately within a tag. You can think of them as
>   alligators eating the whitespace: `>` faces out of the tag and eats
>   the whitespace on the outside, and `<` faces into the tag and eats the
>   whitespace on the inside. They’re placed at the end of a tag
>   definition, after class, id, and attribute declarations but before `/`
>   or `=`.

Comment: This approach does not print HTML. I get literally "<= f.select ....." printed on the final HTML page.

Comment: Is there more to your snippet then those 3 lines? Are they injected in a dif, or just a partial?

Comment: I have added/edited the question to show how I am working out the problem. Does that answer your question? If I use your suggestion it does not print HTML, it literally prints `<= f.select....`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_

It's exactly how it is answered above, except the example is incorrect. Just search on that age and you'll see correct implementation.

Comment: That page does not have the same case like mine. As you can see in my code example, I am not using HAML tags. I am using Ruby on Rails helpers to output the tags. This example is not covered by the page link that you send me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to format it correctly in comments...

Here is quick and... dirty:

```
= select_tag "locations", "<option>Home</option><option selected='selected'>Work</option><option>Out</option>".html_safe   
%span>  
= select_tag "locations", "<option>Home</option><option selected='selected'>Work</option><option>Out</option>".html_safe  
%span>  
= select_tag "locations", "<option>Home</option><option selected='selected'>Work</option><option>Out</option>".html_safe
```

Apparently sticking empty SPAN tag works... (I don't like having to add fake tags, though...